# The method getLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a Double variable

```
Double doubleGrandTotal = 500.00;
```

I am storing it in SharedPreferences like this:

```
editor.putFloat("key_grand_total", Double.doubleToLongBits(doubleGrandTotal));
editor.commit();
```

But, I don't know How can I get this value:

```
double e1 = 0.0;
e1 = pref.getLong("key_grand_total", null);
```

I am getting `The method getLong(String, long) in the type SharedPreferences is not applicable for the arguments (String, null)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should convert long to double to read it from prefs correctly also you should set default value for long, can't be null:

```
double e1 = 0.0;
e1 = Double.longBitsToDouble(pref.getLong("key_grand_total", 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

long cannot be null, u can use

```
e1 = pref.getLong("key_grand_total", 0.0);
```

Comment: you are saving your value as float first and then you are extracting long from it.. Please use this editor.putLong("key_grand_total", Double.doubleToLongBits(doubleGrandTotal));
editor.commit();

Comment: I tapped your answer as useful, but @skrzatswat answer helped to get my target - thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

try

```
double e1 = 0.0;
e1 = pref.getFloat("key_grand_total", 0);
```

second argument is the default value, in case `key_grad_total` is not found in pref, default value is returned to `e1`

Comment: I tapped your answer as useful, but @skrzatswat answer helped to get my target - thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

An easier solution I always do is save the double as a string:

```
editor.putString("key_grand_total", String.valueOf(doubleGrandTotal));
editor.commit();
```

And retrieve it as:

```
double e1 = 0.0;
e1 = Double.parseDouble(pref.getString("key_grand_total", "0"));
```

Comment: Yes. I know and I tapped your answer as useful, but @skrzatswat answer helped to get my target - thank you so much